# Cartesian Product results 0 elements when one of the groups in empty

Tags: visual-studio, linq, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015, cartesian-product

Consider the current cartesian product of 4 groups :

```
var cartesian =  (from elem1 in group1
     from elem2 in group2
     from elem3 in group3
     from elem4 in group4
     select new 
    {
       elem1 , elem2 , elem3 , elem4
    })
```

When one of those groups is empty the result of `cartesian` is 0 elements .

How can I do a cartesian product without taking into account which group is empty or not ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is normal when you get empty set when one of your set in cartesian product is empty.

> How can I do a cartesian product without taking into account which
>   group is empty or not ?

I suggest to use a dummy non-empty set with one element and left joins with truth join conditiin.

```
var cartesian = 
    from dummy in new [] {0} 
    join elem1 in group1 on 1 equals 1 into g1
    from elem1 in g1.DefaultIfEmpty()
    join elem2 in group2 on 1 equals 1 into g2
    from elem2 in g2.DefaultIfEmpty()
    join elem3 in group3 on 1 equals 1 into g3
    from elem3 in g3.DefaultIfEmpty()
    join elem4 in group4 on 1 equals 1 into g4
    from elem4 in g4.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new 
    {
        elem1 , elem2 , elem3, elem4
    };
```

**UPDATE**

As mentioned by @IvanStoev the more simple solution is:

```
var cartesian = 
    from elem1 in group1.DefaultIfEmpty()
    from elem2 in group2.DefaultIfEmpty()
    from elem3 in group3.DefaultIfEmpty()
    from elem4 in group4.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new 
    {
        elem1 , elem2 , elem3 , elem4
    };
```

Comment: What's the difference from appending `DefaultIfEmpty` to each source in the original query construct?

Comment: @IvanStoev, Just as an habit in using left join.